# Orlov's theorem on fully faithful functors between derived categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

According to an important result of Orlov, a $k$-linear exact fully faithful functor $\Phi\colon D^b(X)\rightarrow D^b(Y)$ for smooth projective varieties $X$ and $Y$ is isomorphic to a Fourier-Mukai transform $\Phi_P$. Here $P$ is unique up to isomorphism.

Do we know an example that $P$ is not up to a *canonical* (or say *unique*) isomorphism?

In particular, what can we say about the space of automorphisms on $P$?